# Enabling multiple authentication/authorization plugins in Vernemq

Tags: authentication, plugins, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

When it comes to authentication/authorization in Vernemq, I expected that multiple enabled plugins would be checked in order to determine if a connect/pub/sub is permitted or not.

However, I am experiencing different results in my deployment.

If only one of the auth plugins - either `vmq.acl` or `vmq.diversity` - is enabled, it works as expected.
But, with both plugins enabled, only `vmq.diversity` seems to be working.

What I would like to ask is:

1. Is this the expected behaviour of `vernemq`?
2. If not, how can multiple auth plugins be enabled?
3. With multiple auth plugins enabled, in what order are they checked?

The vernemq service is run via `docker compose` as described below.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml

services:
  vernemq:
    image: vernemq/vernemq
    container_name: vernemq_broker
    environment:
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA=yes

      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=off

      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_PASSWD=on
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_ACL=on
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_ACL__ACL_RELOAD_INTERVAL=10

      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_DIVERSITY=on
      
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__AUTH_POSTGRES__ENABLED=on
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__HOST=auth_db
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__PORT=5432
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__USER=postgres
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__PASSWORD=password
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__DATABASE=postgres
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__POSTGRES__PASSWORD_HASH_METHOD=crypt
      
      # insecure approach to setting password - for testing/development only
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_USER_file_user1=file_user1_password
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_USER_file_user2=file_user2_password

      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LOG__CONSOLE__LEVEL=debuga
    volumes:
      - ./vernemq/vmq.acl:/etc/vernemq/vmq.acl
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    depends_on:
      - auth_db
  auth_db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: vernemq_auth_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./auth_db/init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
```

```
# vmq.acl

user file-user1
topic private/file/#
topic public/#

user file-user2
topic private/file/#
topic public/#
```

The authentication database is initialised with the script:

```sql
-- init-db.sql

CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vmq_auth_acl (
    mountpoint character varying(10) NOT NULL,
    client_id character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    username character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(128),
    publish_acl json,
    subscribe_acl json,
    CONSTRAINT vmq_auth_acl_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (mountpoint, client_id, username)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_user(user_ref text)
LANGUAGE SQL AS 
$$ 
  WITH x AS (
    SELECT ''::text AS mountpoint,
    CONCAT('db-', user_ref, '-client-id')::text AS client_id, -- eg: 'db-user1-client-id'
    CONCAT('db-', user_ref)::text AS username, -- eg: 'db-user1'
    CONCAT('db-', user_ref, '-password')::text AS password, -- eg: 'db-user1-password'
    gen_salt('bf')::text AS salt,
    '[{"pattern": "private/db/#"}, {"pattern": "public/#"}]'::json AS publish_acl,
    '[{"pattern": "private/db/#"}, {"pattern": "public/#"}]'::json AS subscribe_acl
  )
  INSERT INTO vmq_auth_acl (
    mountpoint,
    client_id,
    username,
    password,
    publish_acl,
    subscribe_acl
  )
  SELECT
    x.mountpoint,
    x.client_id,
    x.username,
    crypt(x.password, x.salt),
    publish_acl,
    subscribe_acl
  FROM x ON CONFLICT (mountpoint, client_id, username) DO NOTHING;
$$;
--
--
CALL insert_user('user1'); -- inserts row for user 'db-user1'
CALL insert_user('user2'); -- inserts row for user 'db-user2'
```

With the above configuration and files, there are the following users defined under the following plugins.

1. file-based authentication - `vmq.passwd` plugin

   - `file-user1`
   - `file-user2`
2. authentication via postgres database - `vmq.diversity` plugin

   - `db-user1`
   - `db-user2`

When both plugins are enabled, only the user defined in the database are able to authenticate and connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an authentication plugin (implementing the `auth_on_register`-hook) will give an internal response to the broker. If the plugin authenticates the client, the response will be `ok`. The response can also be `next` to tell the broker that the current plugin cannot authenticate the client, so the broker should just go check the `next` plugin.

This was mostly intended a way to allow users to chain their own plugins. It was not implemented for the file-based plugin, for reasons of compatibility to the Mosquitto format.
You can easily implement a chain in a `vmq_diversity` plugin, though, as you can adapt the Lua scripts.

> ```
> 1. Is this the expected behaviour of vernemq?
> ```

Right now, yes, see above explanation

> ```
> 2. If not, how can multiple auth plugins be enabled?
> ```

By making the plugins return `next` instead of an authentication error. Verne will then just go through all the plugins until it runs out of plugins to ask. You will always see the typical `plugin_chain_exhausted` logged as a reason for a rejected client. Let me know when you need more help with that.

> ```
> 3. With multiple auth plugins enabled, in what order are they checked?
> ```

They are checked in load order (whether you load the plugins internally via `vernemq.conf` file or externally via the plugin enable command). The order should be visible in the `vmq-admin plugin show` command too.